# Single image on page slows down all jquery events significantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file upload form with a data form beside it. Within the regular data form, if certain selections are made within the select then the jquery loads other input fields. But if the user uploads files, they slow down the data form significantly. Images of around 200 KB make all the jquery slow. Why are images affecting my jquery?

I use $(document) in front of all my actions such as

```
$(document).on('mouseover','input[type=button], input[type=submit], a, option',function() {
    $(this).css({'background-position':'100%'});
});
```

Is this the problem? If not, what can I do to fix this. Thanks

**CODE THAT IS SLOW**

```
function DATA_LOAD(TYPE, VALUE) {

TYPE_WIDTH  = $('#'+TYPE).width();
TYPE_HEIGHT = $('#'+TYPE).height();

$('#'+TYPE+'_PROGRESS_END').fadeOut(250);
$('#'+TYPE+'_PROGRESS').css({'background-image':'url(/DISPLAY/load2-2.gif)'}).fadeIn(250);
$('#'+TYPE).css({'min-height': TYPE_HEIGHT,'background':'#000 url(/DISPLAY/load1-1.gif) repeat'});
$('#'+TYPE+'_LOAD').animate({'opacity':'0'}, 250, function() {
    $('#'+TYPE+'_LOAD').load('/LOAD/data.php',{TYPE: TYPE, TYPE_WIDTH: TYPE_WIDTH, VALUE: VALUE}, function() {                                      

        TYPE_HEIGHT = $('#'+TYPE+'_LOAD').show().height();

        $('#'+TYPE+'_LOAD').hide();
        $('#'+TYPE).animate({'min-height': TYPE_HEIGHT}, 250,function() {
            $('#'+TYPE+'_LOAD').css({'display':'block'}); 
            $('#'+TYPE+'_PROGRESS').fadeOut(250);
            $('#'+TYPE+'_LOAD').animate({'opacity':'1'}, 250, function() {
                $('#'+TYPE).css({'background':''}); 
}); }); }); }); }
```

**WHAT I TESTED**

1. I inspected my code within the browser and unchecked all the background images that were being displayed, and the code ran perfectly! But with the images, the jquery is slow as heck. Its super laggy and jittery. The size of images displayed has direct effect on the smoothness of my jquery. Why?
2. I also deleted all jquery except for the above code and it did not effect anything. It was still slow.

Comment: Show us all the code. There is no way for us to know if that causes it to be slow... it could be, but it could also be any other part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This was the format of my layout.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>IMAGES</td>
<td>FORM WITH JQUERY ACTIONS</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Why is a layout with a table screwing up my jquery movements?

**SOLUTION**

Remove table and used floating elements